# Why use the templatestring expression a=`${a}` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, template-strings

I was looking at some javascript code and noticed a line using the template string backticks:

```
a=`${a}`
```

However, this does not seem to have any effect to me as the variable `a` contains a string.

Is this simply a NOP or is there string value for `a` that would make the result differ from the original value?

Comment: plz go through it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` is not a string, doing this will convert the variable to a string, by invoking the `.toString()` available on the object's prototype:

```js
function templateString(d) {
  return `${d}`;
}

console.log(templateString('foo bar'));
console.log(templateString(1337));
console.log(templateString(false));
console.log(templateString(undefined));
console.log(templateString({ 'foo': 1337, 'bar': 'baz' }));
console.log(templateString(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']));
console.log(templateString(function(x) { return x; }));
console.log(templateString(new RegExp('\\w+')));
```

Comment: In my opinion I would prefer the explicit cast using .toString() rather than this implicit way. Less confusion in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The backticks are mostly used for template strings, to concat variables and that kind of stuff.
In this case it is purely used to convert a variable to a string. If the result is going to change will depend on what the variable `a` is used for.

In this case converting it to a string with another technique will not change the outcome.